# Prevent mouse from interacting with another window app

Tags: windows-10, gaming, window

While I play a game in full-screen window mode, I have another window app running, e.g., a web browser to watch videos or read stuff. I have a program called WinLister that I use to make the app window always stay on top.

The problem is when I move and click my mouse while playing the game, the cursor can land on the window app and interact with it and mess things up. Is there a way to prevent this?

EDIT: I have only one monitor and the app is laid on top of the game instead of on another display.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restrict mouse to current display?](https://superuser.com/questions/1088286/how-to-restrict-mouse-to-current-display)

Comment: @Keltari I only have one monitor. The app is laid on top of my game, not on another display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Autohotkey's function WinSet:

```
WinSet, ExStyle, ^0x20, [WinTitle]
WinSet, Transparent, 255, [WinTitle]
```